# Is 0x000001, 0x000002, etc. ever a valid memory address in application level programming?

Tags: c++

Or are those things are reserved for the operation system and things like that?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to use a pointer to store some very small integers if the pointer is "unused".

Comment: @Mike: what's wrong with regular integers?

Comment: This idea sounds so wrong. If it's a pointer, only use it as a pointer. It's like putting a landmine in your hallway when you take a walk, "because the hallway's unused" ;)

Comment: Well mate, look, I always go punk-rock during this project, its demanding it. If those addresses can not occur during normal program execution, I will be fine. That's why I ask it.

Comment: After all, Apple used the top 8 bits of a pointer for special stuff in the original Mac OS. It must be OK.;-)

Comment: If you want to use a var as both a pointer or an `int`, couldn't you just use a `union`?

Comment: On some architecture, only a part of lower address bits are used to addressing memory by memory management unit, then the higher bits can be use to do other things, e.g as control flag of coprocessor. For example, the size of a pointer maybe 64bit, but memory bus is 40bit width, then the high 24bit is not "useful".

Comment: dereferencing a pointer that was created by casting from integer is always an undefined behavior, unless that integer (size compatible) was created by casting a valid pointer in the first place.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: no, you'd need a flag to indicate which type is stored, not just a union.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's unlikely that 0x00000001, etc. will be valid pointers (especially if you use odd numbers on many processors) using a pointer to store an integer value will be highly system dependent.

Are you really that strapped for space?

Edit:

You could make it portable like this:

```
char *base = malloc(NUM_MAGIC_VALUES);
#define MAGIC_VALUE_1 (base + 0)
#define MAGIC_VALUE_2 (base + 1)
...
```

Comment: Yes, I am. I thought about the portability issue. Is it processor, or OS dependent?

Comment: Chances are it will work. But you have no guarantee. It is definitely not portable.

Comment: @Mike Shinola: Probably both. From a strict portability point of view you don't have any real guarantee that it will always work. From a purely pragmatic point of view, however, it should work as long as you never dereference the pointer.

Comment: that is a fking great idea there! Thank you for your great answer.

Comment: Specifically, the standard guarantees that a null pointer doesn't compare equal to any pointer to an object. However, it makes no such guarantee for the result of casting `0x01` to a pointer type. It's up to the C++ implementation what (if anything) is located at those addresses. In practice, this is usually resolved by the OS saying that nothing is located there, but for example on a microcontroller small addresses could well be part of the memory map, corresponding to some register, I/O device, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well the OS is going to give each program it's own virtual memory space, so when the application references memory spaces 0x0000001 or 0x0000002, it's actually referencing some other physical memory address. I would take a look at [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) and [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). So a program will never have access to memory the operating system is using. However I would stay away from manually assigning a memory address for a pointer rather than using `malloc()` because those memory addresses might be text or reserved space.

Comment: Your concept of the OS giving each program its own virtual memory space may not apply to embedded systems. In embedded systems, addresses are often accessed directly without any translations. Some times, memory at 0x00 is reserved for interrupt vectors. The application may write addresses of ISRs into those spaces.

Comment: Neither can you guarantee that any specific virtual address is actually mapped to a real address.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on operating system layout. For User space applications running in  general purpose operating systems, these are inaccessible addresses.

Comment: I doesn't want to dereference the pointer. He wants to save "magic" values in a pointer.

Comment: @Richard, yes since these address are typically not accessible from user mode, he can use these addresses as special tokens. However accidental referencing can cause serious concerns (akin to universe expanding and contracting again to big bang).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to a architecture's virtual address space. Have a loot at this http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs3013/c07/lectures/Section09.1-Intel.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do this:

```
int* myPointer1 = 0x000001;
int* myPointer2 = 0x000032;
```

But do not try to dereference addresses, cause it will end in an Access Violation.
The OS gives you the memory, by the way these addresses are just virtual
the OS hides the details and shows it like a big, continous stripe.

Maybe the 0x000000-0x211501 part is on a webserver and you read/write it through net,
and remaining is on your hard disk. Physical memory is just an illusion from your current viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question C++. I believe that in C++ the address at 0 is reserved and is normally referred to as NULL. Other than that you cannot assume anything. If you want to ask about a particular implementation on a particular OS then that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler/platform, but many older compilers actually have something like the string "(null)" at address 0x00000000. This is a debug feature because that string will show up if a NULL pointer is ever used by accident. On newer systems like Windows, a pointer to this area will most likely cause a processor exception.

I can pretty much guarantee that address 1 and 2 will either be in use or will raise a processor exception if they're ever used. You can store any value you like in a pointer. But if you try and dereference a pointer with a random value, you're definitely asking for problems.

How about a nice integer instead?

Answer (score 0):

Although the standard requires that NULL is 0, a pointer that is NULL does not have to consist of all zero bits, although it will do in many implementations. That is also something you have to beware of if you memset a POD struct that contains some pointers, and then rely on the pointers holding "NULL" as their value.

If you want to use the same space as a pointer you could use a union, but I guess what you really want is something that doubles up as a pointer and something else, and you know it is not a pointer to a real address if it contains low-numbered values. (With a union you still need to know which type you have).

I'd be interested to know what the magic other value is really being used for. Is this some lazy-evaluation issue where the pointer gives an indication of how to load the data when it is not yet loaded and a genuine pointer when it is?

Comment: I don't follow your statement, "Although the standard requires that NULL is 0, a pointer that is NULL does not have to consist of all zero bits, although it will do in many implementations"

Comment: Yes it's tricky but equality to 0 and assignment to 0 is a concept. The same way you could have a class and compare it with 0 and assign it to 0 but that does not mean that 0 state would mean that it would memcmp to all 0 bytes internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on some platforms address 0x00000001 and 0x00000002 are valid addresses.  On other platforms they are not.

In the embedded systems world, the validity depends on what resides at those locations.  Some platforms may put interrupt or reset vectors at those addresses.  Other embedded platforms may place Position Independent executable code there.

There is no standard specification for the layout of addresses.  One cannot assume anything.  If you want your code to be portable then forget about accessing specific addresses and leave that to the OS.

Also, the structure of a pointer is platform dependent.  So is the conversion of the value in a pointer to a physical address.  Some systems may only decode a portion of the pointer, others use the entire pointer value.  Some may use indirection (a.k.a. virtual addressing) to access real objects.  Still no standardization here either.